# Unable to install the missForest package?

Tags: r, missing-data

I would like to install the "missForest" package to process missing data.But I fail to install it successfully.

> install.packages("missForest")
> Warning in install.packages :
> dependency ‘randomForest’ is not available

There is a binary version available but the source
version is later:
binary source needs_compilation
missForest    1.4    1.5             FALSE

What's wrong with my codes? What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried installing `randomForest`? `install.packages('randomForest')`

Comment: >install.packages("randomForest")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘randomForest’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2).     I cannot install this package in my Rstudio

Comment: I have solved this problem by updating the R version, thank u so much ! ! !